# hidden #ignore folder

Tags: windows-7

My Downloads folders has a subfolder named `#ignore` with the following content:

```
30/05/2011  12:42 PM        52,428,800 050.mb
30/05/2011  12:42 PM        62,914,560 060.mb
```

Any ideas where it came from and what it means ? I'm guessing I extracted something I downloaded sometime and it created that folder (it's hidden which is why I didn't notice it at the time).

It seems I'm not the only one with this folder on his drive: https://www.google.com/search?q=ignore+%22050.mb%22+%22060.mb%22&ie=UTF-8

Comment: Get an antivirus installed and scan that folder. Might be interesting.

Comment: MSE didn't find anything...

Comment: Try Malwarebyte's AntiMalware. http://www.malwarebytes.org/

Comment: [Trojan](http://forum.botfrei.de/showthread.php?3776-GVU-Trojaner-nur-bei-Online-Nutzung-%28Windows-VISTA%29)?